# How to list all dropdown values on top of modal?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, web

I am using a dropdown inside the modal.
All the dropdown values are not visible, how to keep dropdown value to be top (now overflow part is hidden).
[image: Values in the Dropdown are hidding]

[image: By Defauly They uses dropdown-content css by changing z-index still issue is not getting resolved]

By changing z-index still issue is not getting resolved.

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: can you tell me the component pack? because some of the component packs dropdown menu support like appendTo={document.body} prop

Comment: For Dropdown Used MDBSelect and for Modal Used MDBModal from MDBReact

Comment: i've read the mdbreact 5 docs and found that mdbselect recieve a prop named options as object and in another doc i found that option normally recieve  data-mdb-reference="parent" as html but couldnt find any doc in react about that. maybe you can do something from here.

Comment: Seems to be a problem with the modal overflow option.

Comment: @Erikm how can i resolve it

Comment: I have no experience in MDBModal but the problem use to be pretty much the same, you can try `.modal { overflow: visible; }
.modal-body { overflow-y: visible; }` or the class names that you have

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove the max-height property.
2. Set `overflow-y:scroll;`